# Trying to get property 'total' of non-object (laravel and vue)

Tags: laravel

i face the problem on the total return the error Trying to get property 'total' of non-object when one of the project that does not contain any report that under one user. How can solve this problem? Any help will be appreaciate. Thank

```html
User
id | name | code | ....

Project(One user can have many projects,One project can have many report)
id | user_id | name | code | ....

Report (One project can have many report.the report is update each month)
id | project_id | amount | date | ....



/project model <br/>
    public function latesReport(){
         return $this->report()->latest('id');
      
    }
   /User model <br/>
   public function total(){
        return $this->project()->get()->sum(function ($projects) {
            return $projects->latestReport()->total;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you update your question by describing DB structure, data & what result you expect ?

Comment: For example, the user have two project. Each project has many report. For the total method inside the user model is to calculate the sum of total column in latest report of each project under that user. The sum of total can be return when every project under that user have at least one report but it return trying to get the property of non object when one of the project under that user does not have the report. The report of each project is update every month. so the project may no have the report at the start time

Comment: i have update the table structure

Comment: just add a condition. if project has `latestReport` then return `latestReport` total else 0.

Comment: i think is because it cannot detect the total column in one of the project. How can solve this?

Comment: `return optional($projects->latestReport())->total ?? 0`

Comment: @MaryTan Which version of Laravel you are using ?

Comment: for this one return optional($projects->latestReport())->total ?? 0 it will directly return 0

Comment: laravel  version 8.58.0

Comment: @MaryTan It will only return 0 when no relationship or total attribute is found.

Answer (score 0):

**User model**

```
public function projects() { 
    return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
}
```

**Projects model**

```
public function user() { 
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function reports() { 
    return $this->hasMany(Report::class);
}

public function latestreport() { 
    return $this->hasOne(Report::class)->latest();
}
```

**Reports model**

```
public function project() { 
    return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
}
```

That sets up the Eloquent relationships. So in the User model to get the total of the latest report for all projects for that user you would use :

```
public function total() { 
    $aggregate = 0;
    $projects = $this->projects;
    foreach($projects as $project) { 
        if($project->latestreport != null) {
             $aggregate += $project->latestreport->total;
        }
    }
    return($aggregate);
}
```

Comment: Hi, will it also return the result when one of the projects does not have report under that user? because now i am facing this problem

Comment: I am trying to sum the total of latest report of each project under each user

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: it always return 0

Comment: I've adjusted the references to the other classes, and also the check to see if latest report exists, but it works - I've created it on my dev machine with test data and it gives the right answers. If not working for you then you need to look at your foreign keys within your database.

Comment: The project does not always have report at the start time. it may have the reoprt after one month

Comment: Irrespective, if there is no report then it returns 0;

Comment: Like I said, check your relationships. I've created it on my dev machine and it works precisely as it should.